# Simulate creating and writing a read only file

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I am trying to debug a permission issue in quite a complex hierarchy of mounted and shared volumes. The operation that fails is captured in the following strace output:

```
open("/git/project.git/objects/12/tmp_obj_FNNWoD", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0444) = 5
write(5, "x\1%\3121\16\3020\f@QfK\276\203\325=\250]\30\262q\222(\5\27,\245\216U\233\242"..., 109) = 109
close(5)                                = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

Notice that a new file is created for read-write but with permissions 0444 which makes it read only. Something is written to a file and file is closed. This is how [git creates temporary files](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0c83680e9c047170614fb08ef222ea4f460e514d/sha1_file.c#L3019). It usually works. But it fails reliably on one of the mounted volumes I have.

I need to find out which layer in the shared folders hierarchy is causing the problem so I would like to try it on different levels of the hierarchy. Problem is that this error is difficult to simulate. It requires git to be installed, I need to initialize new git repository and add files to it etc.

**Is there a way to do this sequence of system calls with some common linux tools?** By standard program I mean something like `sed`, `vim`, `cat`, `echo`, `awk`... Maybe a python script would do too.

Every command I tried just creates a new file with 0644 permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any tools that create a read-write file descriptor with read only permissions, so I took a stab at this using `python3.4`.  I think this should replicate the behavior you referenced in git's source code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    fd = os.open('file.txt', os.O_CREAT | os.O_EXCL | os.O_RDWR, 0o444)
    os.write(fd, 'this is a test\n'.encode())
    os.close(fd)
```

After running the script:

```
$ ls -al file.txt 
-r--r--r-- 1 karl karl 15 Dec  3 12:00 file.txt
$ cat file.txt 
this is a test
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to flag this as a duplicate, but take a look at this:
[Can files be created with permissions set on the command line?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47178/can-files-be-created-with-permissions-set-on-the-command-line)

I think `install -m 444 /dev/null newfile` will do what you need.

Comment: The other question is similar but not the same. I need to create the file as read only and write into it at the same time without doing chmod (because that is what the problematic git command does). I tried the `install` and it works on the broken volume while the git command fails.

Comment: Ahh ok! I'm going to create another answer then.  Sorry for that.